# OpenVPN Server Configuration, not working after 4 days or tutorials and reading

Tags: networking, openvpn

New to networking and this has somewhat been driving me insane for the better part of 4 days now. I have read 5 tutorials and cannot seem to get any of them to work.

[DDWRT Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKlpI.png)

Additional Config

```
push "route 10.217.64.55 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-options DNS 10.217.64.186"
server 10.217.88.0 255.255.255.0

dev tun0
proto udp
keepalive 10 120
```

Code for the client

```
remote myip 1194
client
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-256-cbc
float
tun-mtu 1400
ca ca.crt
cert client2.crt
key client2.key

ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

I tried disabling the firewall in DDWRT, but that had no effect. Here are the IPtables I am currently using, though I have tried about 20 iterations.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 10.217.88.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 10.217.88.1/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.217.88.1/24 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.217.88.1/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Client Log

```
Sat Apr 29 21:04:34 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2017
Sat Apr 29 21:04:34 2017 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Sat Apr 29 21:04:34 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.09
Enter Management Password:
Sat Apr 29 21:04:34 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sat Apr 29 21:04:34 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 WARNING: normally if you use --mssfix and/or --fragment, you should also set --tun-mtu 1500 (currently it is 1400)
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]
Sat Apr 29 21:04:35 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1493517875,WAIT,,,,,,
Sat Apr 29 21:04:52 2017 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Sat Apr 29 21:04:52 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1493517892,EXITING,SIGTERM,,,,,
```

Sever Log

```
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.1 arm-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 27 2017
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.09
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:14
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 WARNING: normally if you use --mssfix and/or --fragment, you should also set --tun-mtu 1500 (currently it is 1400)
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.217.88.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1400 broadcast 10.217.88.255
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET6
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 UDP: Cannot create UDP/UDP6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol (errno=97)
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 Exiting due to fatal error
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 /tmp/openvpn/route-down.sh tun0 1400 1522 10.217.88.1 255.255.255.0 init
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Sun Apr 30 12:32:41 2017 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
```

EDIT: To clarify, my frustration is that I can not get the server and client to handshake and at least respond to each other.

I suspect a symptom of this is checking canyouseeme to see 1194 UPD results in it being closed. Despite the fact that I have the IP table configured as I stated above. Even when turning the firewall off completely it still results in the wait state by OpenVPN.

Comment: Sooooo, how exactly is it not working? Please edit your question to include log messages (both client and server).

Comment: Also, tutorials are very nearly pointless. You need to dig in and truly **understand** those technologies you're working with.

Comment: Looking for server log.

Comment: @EEAA any recommendation on source material to learn about and understand the technologies I am working with?

Comment: OpenVPN manual pages are good to start with. Then, if you encounter terms you don't understand, then look them up in Wikipedia. You should also study what is showing up in TCPDump for UDP port 1194 both in client and server.